# Skip files during installation depending on text file command line argument

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My scenario is currently that I'd like the possibility for users to skip installation of certain files that a user might have specified via a command line argument at install time.

The idea would be for the user to specify a text file and ideally during installation, the installer would check if the file currently being copied is listed in the supplied text file and decide depending on that.

My `[Files]` section atm is referencing full directories: would the best approach be to list all files individually and make use of the `Check` parameter or is there a different approach available? There seems to be no event function that would lend itself for this task.

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to list all files individually. The [`Check` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) is called for each file individually, even when the `Source` is a wildcard.

Use the [`CurrentFilename` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_currentfilename) to tell what file is being processed at the moment.

*Note that the `Check` function is called multiple times for each file.*

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\path\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: AllowFile
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Whitelist: TStringList;

function AllowFile: boolean;
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName := ExtractFileName(ExpandConstant(CurrentFileName));
  Result := (Whitelist = nil) or (Whitelist.IndexOf(Uppercase(FileName)) >= 0);
  if Result then
    Log(Format('Allowing "%s"', [FileName]))
  else
    Log(Format('Skipping "%s"', [FileName]));
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  WhitelistFile: string;
  Lines: TArrayOfString;
  I: Integer;
begin
  WhitelistFile := ExpandConstant('{param:Whitelist}');
  if WhitelistFile = '' then
  begin
    Log('No whitelist specified, allowing all files');
  end
    else
  begin
    Whitelist := TStringList.Create;
    Whitelist.Sorted := True;
    LoadStringsFromFile(WhitelistFile, Lines);
    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Lines) - 1 do
      Whitelist.Add(Uppercase(Lines[I]));
    Log(Format('Loaded %d entries to whitelist from "%s"', [
      Whitelist.Count, WhitelistFile]));
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```